# Getting an empty AJAX response from PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have the following code but its getting an empty response when I check in firebug.

Here is the code:

```
function sendemail() {
    var phone = escape($("#phone").val());
    var reason = escape($("#reason").val());
    var fname = "<?= $_SESSION['fname'];?>";
    var lname = "<?= $_SESSION['lname'];?>";
    var email = "<?= $_SESSION['email'];;?>";
    getAjax("ajax.php?action=sendemail3",
        "Please Wait...",
        "phone" + phone +" & reason "+reason+" & fname "+fname+" & lname "+lname+" & email "+email");
}
```

And here is my PHP code:

```
case "sendemail3":
$name = $_REQUEST['fname'];
$lname = $_REQUEST['lname'];
$to = 'xxx@xxx.edu';
$phone = $_REQUEST['phone'];
$reason = $_REQUEST['reason'];
$subject = 'Verification';
$cont="<html><body style=''> 
<div style='width:100%;' >
<div style='width:50%;margin-left:20%'; >
<div style='text-align:center;font-size:16px;padding:5px;'>
<p>Hi $name $lname,</p>
<p>Thank you <p/>
 </div></div></div>
</body></html>";            
mail ($to, $subject, $cont);
echo "successfully sent";
break;
```

edit getAjax function

```
function getAjax(e, t, n) {
var a = null;
return $.ajax({
    url: e,
    beforeSend: function() {
        $("#notify-container").show(), $("#msg").empty().html(t)
    },
    success: function(e) {
        "gotosearch" == e && (window.location.href = "search.php"), "gotoprofile" == e && (window.location.href = "profile.php"), "hostpage" == e && (window.location.href = "search.php"), "tourpage" == e && (window.location.href = "search.php"), "gotohomenot" == e && ($("#email1").val(""), $("#pass1").val(""), $("#invalid").fadeIn("fast"), document.getElementById("invalid1").style.display = "none", document.getElementById("invalid2").style.display = "none"), "gohome" == e && ($("#email1").val(""), $("#pass1").val(""), $("#invalid2").fadeIn("fast"), document.getElementById("invalid1").style.display = "none", document.getElementById("invalid").style.display = "none"), "gonot" == e && ($("#email1").val(""), $("#pass1").val(""), document.getElementById("invalid").style.display = "none", document.getElementById("invalid2").style.display = "none", $("#invalid1").fadeIn("fast"))
    },
    type: "POST",
    data: n,
    async: !1
}), a
}
```

When I check in firebug the values does get send to the in a post but when I look at the response its empty. 
Anything I could do to fix it?

Thank you.

Comment: What is the variable `r` as displayed in the ajax parameters `"phone"+phone+r"+reason` ~ is that a mistake?

Comment: @RamRaider thanks i corrected that but am still getting an empty response

Comment: Maybe there is a missing break after the echo and the flow of the program continues until the next case and it does something? If you don't show us the full source, it's hard to guess.

Comment: @dlopez there's only
    break;
after that line. the problem is that even the $name = $_REQUEST['fname']; is not returning anything if i print the $name.

Comment: Can you show us the code for the function getAjax? If the third argument is supossed to be an urlenconded string, then you have to use an equal (=) foreach assignment.

Comment: @dlopez i added it above

Comment: As I expected, you're sending the data like if it were a kind of query string, but in fact it doesn't. In that way, you have two options: send your data as plain old javascript object, or use a string in a query string format. it's up to you to choose what method to use. If you use the query string format it should be something like this: `"phone=" + phone +"&reason=" + reason + "&fname=" + fname + "&lname="  + lname  + "&email=" + email"`